# Refer coin Firebase database multiples the coins until app crashes

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I've added refer coin system to my app in which if you refer it to someone you get 100 coins & the person refers code you were using get's the same. Bu the issue is when I run the app and use the referral code coins keep on increasing unless the app crashes. Coins should be added 100 in both accounts but they go from 0 to 24000 or more unless the app crashes.

The following code is :

```
reference
                        .addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {

                        ProfileModel model = snapshot.child(oppositeUID).getValue(ProfileModel.class);
                        ProfileModel myModel = snapshot.child(user.getUid()).getValue(ProfileModel.class);

                        int coins = model.getCoins();
                        int updatedCoins = coins + 100;

                        int myCoins = myModel.getCoins();
                        int myUpdate = myCoins + 100;

                        HashMap<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
                        map.put("coins", updatedCoins);

                        HashMap<String, Object> myMap = new HashMap<>();
                        myMap.put("coins", myUpdate);

                        reference.child(oppositeUID).updateChildren(map);
                        reference.child(user.getUid()).updateChildren(myMap)
                                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                        dialog.dismiss();
                                        Toast.makeText(InviteActivity.this, "Congrats", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    }
                                });

                    }
```

Comment: Change addValueEventListener to addListenerForSingleValueEvent. Does it work now the way you want?

Comment: Yes, this one helped thank you soo much brother this code just made me mad from last 4 hours thank you once again @Alex Mano. How i could be so dumbb i didn't noticed this !!!!

Comment: Hi @ChocoDev - the preferred way to say "Thanks" around here is to upvote useful answers, and accept the one (if any) that helped you solve your problem - which you can do in this case.

Answer (score 1):

The problem in your code lies in the fact that you are using addValueEventListener. This means that you are listening for changes in real-time. Every time something changes in your database, the listener fires. Since you are listening to the same location you are performing the updates, the listener fires over and over again. What you need is addListenerForSingleValueEvent, to get the data exactly once.

To solve this, simply change the call to:

```
addValueEventListener()
```

To:

```
addListenerForSingleValueEvent()
```

And your code will work perfectly fine.